# How to connect to IBM COS API using C# and perform bucket operations

Tags: c#, trigonometry

We have few buckets in cloud object store, along with the Bucket CRN ,Service endpoint ,API key for service ID. How can we perform bucket operations in C# using these details.

We tried installing the .Net SDK for AWS S3, but none are accepting the apikey.